# jQuery if/else nested statement

Tags: html, jquery, if-statement, nested

Consider the following code, which adds a sticky header on scroll to a page where a certain ID "sticky-header" is present and window size is greater than 425

```
    sticky : function() {
        var stickyTools = $j('#sticky-header');
        if (stickyTools.length > 0 && window.outerWidth > 425) {
            var headerHeight = stickyTools.height();
            var fixmeTop = stickyTools.offset().top + headerHeight - 50;
            $j(window).scroll(function() {
                var currentScroll = $j(window).scrollTop();
                if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
                    stickyTools.addClass('sticky');
                } else {
                    stickyTools.removeClass('sticky');
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Now this works fine on one template but on another template I want to re-use the same functionality but ONLY if a check box is selected. The checkboxes have the class of "item-checkbox". I have a unique ID on that page which is "template-list".

I am unsure of the best way to nest another IF statement within the current one (if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop)) or if there is a more clever way of doing this?

Comment: Use `&&` to perform multiple checks `if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop && $(".item-checkbox:checked").length > 0)`

Comment: But the other page doesn't have checkboxes. Therefore that won't work. Only the page with the id "template-list" has checkboxes.

Comment: You can also check if there are any checkboxes. `&& ($(".item-checkbox").length == 0 || $(".item-checkbox:checked").length > 0)`

Comment: But what about the template that has no checkboxes? That && statement would never be true there?

Comment: No, it WILL be true because `$(".item-checkbox").length == 0`.

Comment: So it's true if there are no checkboxes, or there are checkboxes and at least one of them is checked.

Comment: Thats right. Im just trying to modify the current script to work on a page that has checkboxes without repeating the whole block of code again.